# Ошибка при проверке на ошибку

Tags: golang

Есть программа на Go и небольшой кусок кода поведение которого непонятно.
Рабочий код:

```
exec.Command("explorer", ("http://127.0.0.1:8000")).Run()
exec.Command("explorer", ("https://127.0.0.1:8001")).Run()
```

Но go lint ругается что нет проверки на ошибку. Ну ок делаем самую банальную проверку.
Получается так:

```
err := exec.Command("explorer", ("http://127.0.0.1:8000")).Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
err2 := exec.Command("explorer", ("https://127.0.0.1:8001")).Run()
if err2 != nil {
    log.Fatal(err2)
}
```

и тут оказывается что программа крашится с ошибкой

```
exit status 1
```

В чем тут может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вероятно, один из `Run()`-ов завершается с ненулевым кодом.

Comment: Допустим возможно. Но почему вылетает только когда есть проверка на ошибки? Без нее то все ок. И не нулевой код по идее должен отобразить в консоли и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, один из `Run()`-ов завершается с ненулевым кодом.

---

https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal

> `Fatal` is equivalent to `Print()` followed by a call to `os.Exit(1)`.

то есть

> `Fatal` - то же самое, что вызов `Print()` с последующим вызовом `os.Exit(1)`.

---

Замените `Fatal()` на `Print()`.

Comment: Да все работает спасибо!